# Altium 2019 - "PLACE" option is not highlighted/showing

Tags: pcb-design

I've recently downloaded Altium 2019 (version 20). When I was searching for the components using the manufacturer part number, I was not able to place the searched part as the "PLACE" option was not highlighted. What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps to get some traction here you could add what component, which manufacturer, a screenshot, which libraries you have loaded etc...

Answer (score 1):

Check that your licensing is valid and you have a good connection to the license server.

Without a valid license checked out, Altium (silently) goes into a read-only mode that is useful for viewing but not editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'v seen this issue too, there seem to be a bug since after updating to latest updates and restarting, it worked.